# How do I successfully implement Google Mobile Ads and Google Play Services into my Unity arcade game?

Tags: unity, google-play-services, google-play, monetization, advertisements

I have been trying for like a month now to properly implement Google Play Services and Google Mobile Ads into my Unity Android Game. I have had success in getting Google Play Services to work but when I added Google Mobile Ads at first it didn't work. I just didn't see any ads pop up. Now when I build my app it won't open it just crashes. Not exactly sure what I did.
I have configured all the services correctly according to my knowledge and I'm am just using code from the documentation for the ads.
Heres that code:

```
public static AdManager Instance { set; get; }

public string bannerId;
public string videoId;
public string deviceId;
BannerView bannerView;
InterstitialAd interstitial;

private void Start ()
{
    Instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(videoId);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(deviceId).Build();
    // Load the banner with the request.
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
}

public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        interstitial.Show();
}
```

I am using the correct ad Ids, I double checked that. I don't know what else to do. 
I can provide any other information you may need upon request.

Anyone with experience with this would be super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: When the game crashes on the device do you get a message on screen?

Comment: No, there's nothing to tell me whats wrong. I am using an emulator but I didn't think that would affect anything, does it? @TartleWizard

Comment: I recently had an issue like this with Unity 5 and I had to update my jdk install and I redownloaded and updated all of android studio. After that my game ran with the services and the ads.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official guide on implementing `AdMob` to your game:
https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start

You basically download the scene on top of this website and import it through `Assets -> Import -> Custom Package`.

Then you restart Unity and your code editor to apply library changes and make the namespace visible.

Then, you create a script called `AdmobManager` and put inside:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdmobManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private InterstitialAd staticAd;

    void Awake () {
        LoadStaticAd(); // load it first time
    }

    private void LoadStaticAd(){
        if(staticAd != null) staticAd.Destroy();
        staticAd = new InterstitialAd("ca-app-pub-###/###"); // put here the ID of the static ad from the admob website
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        // you can add a test device id to test the ads on your phone before releasing the game
        // download this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pe.go_com.admobdeviceidfinder&hl=pl
        // to find the correct id of your device
        //  .AddTestDevice("################################").Build(); 
            .Build();

        staticAd.LoadAd(request);
        staticAd.OnAdClosed += OnAdClosed; // ad a listener to reload the ad when user finishes watching it
    }


    private void OnAdClosed(object ob, EventArgs args){
        LoadStaticAd(); // when the ad is closed, reload the ad in background
    }


    public void ShowStaticAd(){
        if(staticAd != null && staticAd.IsLoaded()){ // safety checks
            staticAd.Show();
        }
    }   

    private static AdmobManager instance; // singleton pattern to access the AdmobManager anywhere
    public static AdmobManager Instance() {
        if(!instance){
            instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof (AdmobManager)) as AdmobManager;
            if(!instance)
                Debug.Log("There need to be at least one active AdmobManager on the scene");
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Remember to replace the ad ID with your own from the `AdMob` website. You can also put your `DeviceID` to test the ads when you're in the Beta phase and the game isn't published yet.

To show an ad in the game, you do:

```
void LevelFinished(){
    AdmobManager.Instance().ShowStaticAd();
}
```

And that's it.

There are two ways on implementing this. One from the tutorial above and one from the `Unity Admob Plugin`. I've tried 6 times implementing `Admob Plugin` from github, always crashes the device, ALWAYS. This guide above worked for 4 games so far on `Unity 5.5` and Unity `5.6`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used admob in my earlier work. Check the code here;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AdMobPlugin))]
public class ReklamAdmob : MonoBehaviour
{

public GUISkin skin;
private const string AD_UNIT_ID = "YourAdUnitId";
private const string INTERSTITIAL_ID = "YourInterstirialId";
private AdMobPlugin admob;
public Score other2;

public bool hidden = true;


public void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}

public void Start()
{
    admob = GetComponent<AdMobPlugin>();
    admob.CreateBanner(AD_UNIT_ID, AdMobPlugin.AdSize.SMART_BANNER, true, INTERSTITIAL_ID);
    admob.RequestAd();
    admob.HideBanner();
}

// Update is called once per frame

public void Update()
{
    if(other2.CurrentScore<=0 && hidden==true)
    {
        admob.RequestInterstitial();
        hidden=false;
    }

}


void OnEnable()
{
    AdMobPlugin.InterstitialLoaded += HandleInterstitialLoaded;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    AdMobPlugin.InterstitialLoaded -= HandleInterstitialLoaded;
}

void HandleInterstitialLoaded()
{
    admob.ShowInterstitial();
}
}
```

But i've used Unity Ads, which seems better for me.

If you did not check it yet look [here](https://unity3d.com/services/ads). Implementation is much easier.

Comment: Admob and Google Mobile Ads are a little different. There are two different repositories for the unity plugins. I tried using Admob first but a friend of mine told me Google Mobile Ads is easier to implement so I switched to that. @EmreE