# Google Play Services Library not found. How can I get this?

Tags: unity, google-play-services, google-play

So this question is in relation to, but not the same as my previous question ([How do I successfully implement Google Mobile Ads and Google Play Services into my Unity arcade game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/137585/83789)). That is why I am making a new one. I am almost ready to publish my app now the I have ads working but in the process of implementing Unity Ads I was forced to re-implement Google Play Services. I did so with an updated version of Google Play Services and now I am receiving this error:
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after much research I found the solution here: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1193742/view.html
Google Play Services is now successfully integrated.

---

*Now the only problem is my app crashes on start after I build it to my device :/ Idk what to do at this point.*